# second drop down box is not updating depending on value selected in first drop down box django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I have two drop down boxes in my django form, The first drop down box contains the makes of cars (audi,BMW) , the second drop down box contains the different models eg audi A1. I am trying to dynamically update the second drop down box depending on what the user selects in the first drop down box. I am trying to use jquery and ajax to do this, the problem I am having is passing the kwargs to my second drop down box.

view

```
def chose_car_make_model(request):


    if 'car' in request.GET:
        car_id =  request.GET['car']
        car_model_id = CarModel.objects.filter(id=car_id)
        form = ChoseCarMakeModelForm(request.POST,ids=car_model_ids)
        return render(
            request,
            template_name = 'form.html',
            dictionary = {
                'form':form,
            }
        )
    else:

        if request.method == "POST":

            form = ChoseCarMakeModelForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                car_model = form.cleaned_data['car_model']
                car_make = form.cleaned_data['car_make']


                car = CarOwner(
                    car_model = car_model,
                    car_make = car_make
                    owner = request.User
                    )


                # Go to the next form in the process.
                return redirect('view_car')
                #return render(request, 'riskregister/menus/riskregister_index.html')

        # Initial form
        else:

        form = ChoseCarMakeModelForm()

        return render(
        request,
        template_name = 'form.html',
        dictionary = {
            'form':form,
            }
        )
```

forms.py

```
class ChoseCarMakeModelForm(forms.Form):


    car_makes = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=CarMake.objects.all().order_by('name'),
        label = "Make:",
        widget = Select(attrs={'class': 'span6 small-margin-top small-margin-bottom'}),
        empty_label = "Select a make of car",
        required=True
    )


    car_model = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=CarModel.objects.all(makes=car_model_ids).order_by('name'),
        label = "Model:",
        widget = Select(attrs={'class': 'span6 small-margin-top small-margin-bottom'}),
        empty_label = "Select a model of car",
        required=True
    )
        def __init__(self, car_model_ids, *args, **kwargs):
            super(ChoseCarMakeModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

            # set the user_id as an attribute of the form
            self.car_model_ids = car_model_ids
```

models

```
class CarMake(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

class CarModel(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    make = models.ForignKey('CarMake')
```

jquery

```
$("#car_make").change(function(){

var make_id = $(this).val()

 $.ajax({
        url: "{% url chose_car_make_model %}",
        data: {
          car:make_id
        },
        success: function (data) {

        }
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case it will contain the html code of your whole page. In this case you need to have an API view which returns say JSON output, and in ajax success function you update the second dropdown using the JSON you got. Please also consider trying REST API for such tasks.
If you want to use your own api response you can consider such a function as response in views:

```
def api_response(success, payload={}):
  response = JsonResponse({
    'status': 'success' if success else 'error',
    'payload': payload
  })

  response.status_code = 200 if success else 400
  response['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'
  return response
```

than use the data.payload in success function of the ajax call.

You also may want to consider using API URLs, by defining "apipatterns" in urls.py